# Edge indices of array with cube data

Tags: arrays, math, set

If I have array representing a cube with side length of n, the array length is n * n * n.

If for example n=4 and array is 64 long, I want to have a list of the indices that are at the outer layer of the cube. So something like 0-15, 16-19, 20, 23, 24, 27, 28-31, 32-35, 36, 39, 40, 43, 44-47, 48-63.

I know it is some creative use of mod and div, but I'm getting confused.

Comment: Just have three nested loops and an external counter variable, which gets incremented in the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
I, n: Integer;
begin
Memo1.Lines.Clear;
n := 4;
for I := 0 to n*n*n-1 do
begin
  if (I mod n) = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  X min')

  else if (I mod n) = (n-1) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  X max')

  else if ((I div n) mod n) = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  Y min')

  else if ((I div n) mod n) = (n-1) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  Y max')

  else if ((I div n) div n) = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  Z min')

  else if ((I div n) div n) = (n-1) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  Z max')

  else
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.ToString + '  ')
end;
end;
```

Produces a list:

```
0  X min
1  Y min
2  Y min
3  X max
4  X min
5  Z min
6  Z min
7  X max
8  X min
9  Z min
10  Z min
11  X max
12  X min
13  Y max
14  Y max
15  X max
16  X min
17  Y min
18  Y min
19  X max
20  X min
21  
22  
23  X max
24  X min
25  
26  
27  X max
28  X min
29  Y max
30  Y max
31  X max
32  X min
33  Y min
34  Y min
35  X max
36  X min
37  
38  
39  X max
40  X min
41  
42  
43  X max
44  X min
45  Y max
46  Y max
47  X max
48  X min
49  Y min
50  Y min
51  X max
52  X min
53  Z max
54  Z max
55  X max
56  X min
57  Z max
58  Z max
59  X max
60  X min
61  Y max
62  Y max
63  X max
```